# How to use react on new web pages after the default

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I created a new project using react. After the first page(landing) for which java script and react is already linked to the webpage how can I use my old react elements and new one on the consecutive pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a completely new page: The same way.

You create a React application, and then initialize it on the page with something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
                <App />
        </React.StrictMode>,
        document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Typically, however, you **wouldn't** load a new page.

The user would interact with the React app, and your code would change the state which would change what was displayed on the page. This can be combined with [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) to create deep links into the application and some kind of server-side rendering (such as [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)) to make those deep links work in an accessible and SEO friendly way.